# Power BI - Calculate number of consecutive years by group

Tags: group-by, powerbi, powerquery

I have a grouped table of customers and years. I would like to add a column to identify how many consecutive years the member has been a customer.

| ID | Year |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2019 |
| A | 2020 |
| A | 2021 |
| A | 2022 |
| B | 2019 |
| B | 2021 |
| B | 2022 |

The added formula should calculate the number of consecutive years as a customer, resetting when  a year is skipped.

| ID | Year | Yrs_Cust |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2019 | 0 |
| A | 2020 | 1 |
| A | 2021 | 2 |
| A | 2022 | 3 |
| B | 2019 | 0 |
| B | 2021 | 0 |
| B | 2022 | 1 |

Comment: Do you want a DAX solution or Power Query?

Comment: I suppose either would be fine. I'm new to Power BI and haven't ventured into using Power Query functionality yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another alternative.

[image]

Add a single column with the following code:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each [
a = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", (x)=> [ID]= x[ID]), 
b = List.Select( a[Year], (x)=> x <= [Year] ),
c = List.Reverse(b),
d = List.Accumulate(c, [now = [Year], run = 0],(state, current)=> [now = state[now]-1, run = if current  = state[now] then state[run] + 1 else state[run] ])[run]-1
][d])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

[image]

Group rows.

[image]

Add custom column.

[image]

Expand the custom column.

Add another custom column.

[image]

Add a final custom column.

[image]

```
[a= Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom1", (x)=> [ID]=x[ID] and [delta] = x[delta]  ),
b = List.Min(a[Year]),
c = [Year] - b
][c]
```

Remove redundant columns.

Full code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", type text}, {"Year", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"ID"}, {{"All", each _, type table [ID=nullable text, Year=nullable number]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Table.AddIndexColumn([All],"index")),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"ID", "All"}),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Custom", {"ID", "Year", "index"}, {"ID", "Year", "index"}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Custom", "delta", each [Year]-[index]),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Custom", each [a= Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom1", (x)=> [ID]=x[ID] and [delta] = x[delta]  ),
        b = List.Min(a[Year]),
        c = [Year] - b
        ][c]),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom2",{"index", "delta"})
in
    #"Removed Columns1"
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"ID"}, {{"data", each 
    let #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each try #"Added Index"{[Index]-1}[Year] otherwise null),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom.1", each if [Custom]=null or [Year]-[Custom]>1 then [Year] else null),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom1",{"Custom.1"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filled Down", {"Custom.1"}, {{"data", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index2", 0, 1, Int64.Type), type table }}),
    #"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"ID", "Year", "Index2"}, {"ID", "Year", "Index2"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded data",{"Custom.1"})
in #"Removed Columns"
, type table }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Year", "Index2"}, {"Year", "Index2"})
in
#"Expanded data"
```

Comment: I came up with another idea using List.Accumulate - thoughts on performance compared to what we already have?

Comment: very elegant. I've found that list accumulate is a dog in performance when doing the multiple column split thing, but for this case, likely it works fine.  I thought of doing a list.accumulate method yesterday, but this was faster to write  (the => x <= made me wonder if I had missed some key syntax all these years, till I realized what was going on)

Comment: Oh yeah, it looks weird when I read it back. That's the problem with PQ - it is easy to write but difficult to parse and interpret when reading back. Good to know about the performance issues when splitting columns.